# How to get values from JSON XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, web

I am new to web development, and I am using a XMLHttpRequest() in JavaScript to get data from an api. I am trying to create variables from the data but am getting an error when I try to do the following. Does anyone know what is wrong with the line `var data1 = data["data1"];`?

```
<script>
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = "www.mytestapi.com/response.json";
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();
                    
    Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        var json = JSON.parse(Http.responseText)
        var data = json.Data
        var data1 = data["data1"]; //issue caused here
    }
<script>
```

Comment: And the error is?  And the json data looks like?  Edit the question and show the complete error and sample json.

Comment: What error did you get when you tried this?

Comment: After var data = json.Data, add console.log('data:',data); and tell us what do you get in the console, this will help to figure out about the error.

Comment: read what [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readystatechange_event) actually is - understand that it gets called multiple times during the request phases, even before there is any data available, then use `onload` instead

Comment: @pid - doesn't matter when you attach the handler, and `responseText` actually is in the `XHR` object

Comment: To fully answer the question, we would need to see an example of the data you receive ... since it needs to be JSON representation of an object with a top level property called exactly `Data` .... i.e. would expect something like `{"Data":{"data1":"some value"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to parse response data, data is parsed already , try  this

```
   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = "www.mytestapi.com/response.json";
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = () => {
        console.log("load - "+ JSON.stringify(xhr.response));
        var data = xhr.response;
        var data1 = data["data1"]
    }
     xhr.onerror = () => {
        console.log("error status - " + xhr.status);
    }
    xhr.send()
```